# How to use insertRow() and deleteRow() function in SAPui5 Table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using `sap.ui.table.Table` control.

Now, I manually process the JSON and adding a row. But I want to use `insertRow()` and `deleteRow()` function. I tried using that function but it showing error as

> can not be used Programmatically.

Please give suggestion on how to use these function in SAPUI5

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is not possible. This is the only explanation I have, in case you follow function signature.
Recommended way is to use the data binding. [docs](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html)
Assuming data is [] of {} (typical for xsjs return) and table is your table I would do it like this:

```
1. iterate through keys of data[0] and add corresponding columns to a table.
2. table.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data)).bindRows("/");
```